# Button label and section title are same, which are next to each other

Tags: gui-design, user-behavior

I got this question from one of my colleague which I did not realize at the time of wireframing.

I have a button which says "Advanced Search" when you click on it, which shows/hide s section titled as "Advanced Search".

Does it make sense to have Section title again since it is already there on the button?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's redundant.

The button becomes the title, the problem is how graphically **integrate** the button to the form/text body so that it fulfills its double function of button and title at the same time.

There are some graphic and interactive solutions.

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

See this [working example](https://www.renfert.com/gbr-en)